# How do I create binary matrix with specific pattern of 1s and 0s efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How can I create a binary table of this alternating pattern efficiently in python? The 1s repeat for 4 elements then 0s for another 4 elements and so on and so forth as shown below:

```
101010 
101010
101010
101010
010101
010101
010101
010101
101010
101010
 ...
```

Comment: How will you use this data? That could help decide the most efficient solution. Are the values constant or do they need to be parameterised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `numpy.tile`

```
import numpy as np

one_zero = np.tile([1, 0], 12).reshape(4, 6)
"""
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
"""
zero_one = np.tile([0, 1], 12).reshape(4, 6)
"""
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
"""
ar = np.tile([[1, 0], [0, 1]], 12).reshape(8, 6)
"""
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
table = [('101010', '010101')[x//4%2 == 1] for x in range(100)]
```

You may prefer use 0b101010 and 0b010101 instead of string, but the result printed will be 42 and 21.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `np.resize`, `np.repeat`, and `np.eye` for this:

```
np.resize(np.repeat(np.eye(2), 4, axis = 0), (1000, 6))
```

`np.resize` takes a pattern and copies it in every direction out to the target size.