# How do I repeat binary pattern and ratio in matrix effectively in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to efficiently print a matrix in python that follows a specific pattern in the columns of 5 0s then 3 1s then 5 0s and so on and so forth as shown below for 1000 rows:

```
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
1111
1111
1111
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
1111
1111
1111
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `np.block` and list comprehension:

```
out = np.block([[np.zeros((5, 4))],[np.ones((3, 4))]] * 125).astype(int)
```

This can be functionalized to answer [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993372/how-do-i-create-binary-matrix-with-specific-pattern-of-1s-and-0s-efficiently) questions like so:

```
def block_repeat(size, *args):
    block = np.block([[a] for a in args])
    return np.resize(block, (size,) + block.shape[1:])

block_repeat(1000, np.zeros((5,4)), np.ones((3,4)))
Out[]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: Another way to do this is `np.resize([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1], (4, 1000)).T`, but it's a bit hackier.

Answer (score 2):

This didn't use `numpy` but it does the job. You can later convert it into a `numpy matrix` using `numpy.matrix`.

```
import itertools

cycle = itertools.cycle([("0") for i in range(5)] + [("1") for i in range(3)])

for i in range(1000):
  item = next(cycle)
  print(4 * item)
```

Output -

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
11111
11111
11111
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
11111
11111
11111
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]] for i in range(125)])
```

You can check the shape. It has 125 rows of 8 rows i.e. 1000:

```
>>> my_array.shape
(125, 8, 4)
```

To print it you can use:

```
count_row = 0
for row in my_array:
    for row2 in row:
        print(row2)
        count_row += 1
```

Output:

```
# count_row is equal to 1000.

[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0]
....
```

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of @Ishan golfing this, here it is in one line, no librarys:

```
print("\n".join(["00000111"[i % 8] * 4 for i in range(1000)]))

# Explanation
pattern = "00000111"
for i in range(1000):
    index = i % len(pattern)
    print(pattern[index] * 4)
```

Comment: Very similar spirit to my `np.resize([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],(4,1000)).T` hack :P

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.tile`, you can even avoid using list comprehension:

```
>>> unit = np.repeat([0] * 5 + [1] * 3, 4)
>>> # you can also use unit = [0] * 20 + [1] * 12,
>>> # but using ndarray as the parameter of np.tile is faster than list.
>>> np.tile(unit, 2).reshape(-1, 4)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> np.tile(unit, 125).reshape(-1, 4)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```